# Can't seem to grasp populating Observable with data from server

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm pretty proficient with Angularjs, but am new to Angular and am having trouble populating an observable in my component with a service call I'm making to the server.

The service is fine and returns what I'm looking for, but populating the observable doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Campaigns } from '../campaigns';
import { CampaignListService } from './campaign-list.service'
import { Subscription, Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-campaign-list',
  templateUrl: './campaign-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./campaign-list.component.scss']
})
export class CampaignListComponent implements OnInit {
  campaigns$: Observable<Campaigns[]>;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private campaignListService:CampaignListService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.campaignListService.getCampaigns().subscribe(campaigns => this.campaigns$ = campaigns);
   console.log(this.campaigns$);
  }

}
```

and here is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class CampaignListService {

  constructor(private _http:Http) { }

  getCampaigns(){
    return this._http.get('http://example.com/api/campaign')
        .map(res => res.json())
  }

}
```

From what I've seen in the tutorials, this looks like I should be able to console log the campaigns$ observable, but I get an undefined.

Any insight would be really appreciated!

Comment: It logs undefined because it actually is undefined when you log it. The subscribe callback is asynchronous, so `campaigns$` get its value assigned after the console.log call executes. Move the log call inside the callback and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, Head Rush. I was able to do that previously to test, but what I'm trying to do is populate a variable that I can call in an ngFor loop. The var is campaigns$, so I figured I could populate it and call it form the console...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
this.campaignListService.getCampaigns().subscribe(data => this.campaigns$);
```

should be

```
this.campaigns$ = this.campaignListService.getCampaigns();
```

Your service returns an `Observable<Campaigns[]>` (athough it doesn't specify it as a return value, but should), and you just want to store that Observable in your component.

If you wanted to store the array of campaigns, *emitted* by the observable, in your component, then you would have to subscribe and do

```
this.campaignListService.getCampaigns().subscribe(campaigns => this.campaigns = campaigns);
```

Comment: Thanks JB, but I'm getting this error: [ts]
Type 'Observable<() => any>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Campaigns[]>'.
  Type '() => any' is not assignable to type 'Campaigns[]'.
    Property 'includes' is missing in type '() => any'.

Comment: Your service is wrong, too. `res.json` should be `res.json()`. That would have been detected by the TS compiler if you had specified the return type for your method.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, JB. I updated my post to reflect the code as you described, but still get undefined. What else could I be missing. Thanks!

Comment: No, you mixed the two solutions. Aither you want the observable in your component, and you use my first snippet, or you want the array emitted by the observable, and you use the second one. If you use the second one, the variable should be named `campaigns`, and must be of type `Campaigns[]`, not Observable. If you choose the second way, you need to realize that the array is emitted **asynchronously**, long after you have subscribed. So the value logged by the console.log statement will log undefined, as expected.

Comment: You can't eat toasted bread just after you put it in the toaster. You need to wait for the toaster to tell you that the bread is toasted.

Comment: JB, follow up question: How do you specify the return type for my method in the service. It was my understanding that the get() method is returning an observable of type response. How do you change that to the <Campaigns[]> type?